# Ability to access 2GB files for external system

Tags: apex, soap-api, rest, soap, contentversion

I am trying to grab large VersionData from ContentVersion for a REST service but HTTPCallout and HttpRequest only allows 12MB (Async).  How can I get access to the 2GB files?  Would that be through the SOAP service?  Is SOAP going to be deprecated?   Is there any other way to get at those files?

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do? You can't access more than 12 MB not just because of HttpRequest limit, but heap limits as well. You will need to arrange for a third party to handle the transfer, either a web browser or a server you set up.

Comment: I am trying to upload files to OneDrive and "replace" the Salesforce files functionality by activating a trigger on ContentVersion and then using rest to transfer the files to OneDrive.  The OneDrive API only uses REST for upload where I'll hit the heap issues.  I wouldn't object using a special server or web browser.  Ideally I'd do neither.  But special server would allow a "replacement" of files, webbrowser would not require a 3rd party/external server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way you're going to access 2GB of data in Apex Code, so you'll want to use either a web browser or a server you set up, such as Heroku or AWS EB. Either way, you're looking for the [Salesforce Files](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/features_files.htm) API so that you can get the file, then transfer it to OneDrive. Salesforce Files is part of the Chatter API, which is RESTful. If you want to do it directly from the web browser, you can use the [AJAX Proxy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_proxy.htm) to get around the CORS security features of browsers.

Comment: Excellent.  I'll look into these and check back!  Thanks so much! I may use Azure Function or Sharepoint online.

Comment: is it possible to convert these blob's to byte streams or get access to the body if they are under 4 MB?

Comment: it could be partially related to this question:  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/184340/convert-contentversion-blob-to-bytestream-for-onedrive-upload-ms-graph-api?noredirect=1#comment277755_184340